# emacs shell-mode follows its default-directory to current-file

Tags: emacs

When I enter `cd c:/dir/to/path` in shell mode, shell mode follows its `default-directory` to `c:/dir/to/path` and that's good. But while visiting a certain file(c:/another/dir/file.ext), how can I let the existing shell directory to that one without entering `cd c:/antoher/dir/file.ext` ?

Is there any pre-exisiting function for that in emacs? searched quite a lot but not found unfortunately.

I'm using Emacs 24.2.1 in Win7.

EDIT:

I've written a not-good-looking function like followings. Any proposal/advice will be appreciated(I'm a novice in elisp).
(With prefixed interactive call, it will show shell buffer with current directory. I'm repeatedly thinking there might be something already invented one better than this).

```
  (defun my-shell-with-current-directory (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((sp (get-process "shell"))
         (spbuf (and sp (process-buffer sp)))
         (dir (if buffer-file-name (file-name-directory buffer-file-name) default-directory)))
    (if (and arg sp spbuf dir)
        (progn 
          (comint-simple-send sp (concat "cd /d " dir))
          (display-buffer spbuf)
          (save-excursion
            (set-buffer spbuf)
            (cd dir)
            )
          )
      (progn
        (shell)
        (comint-simple-send sp "setlocal enableextensions")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set default-directory using setq at any time.
You may add that code as a hook onto find-file-hooks.
Also you may advice find-file command with the setting wished.
So far just my thoughts...

Comment: Thanks for comment. I added a roughly written interactive function after reading your idea. Please take a look at and any advice will be appreciated.